# Adding parameters to the POST Analyze method

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

https://westus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomModel

In the above documentation there is the following URL which implies you ought to be able to analyze a form for a specific Key value

[https://{endpoint}/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/models/{id}/analyze[?keys]](https://%7Bendpoint%7D/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/models/%7Bid%7D/analyze[?keys])

I have trained a model of my own and when I use the Get Keys method this is what gets returned...

```
{"clusters":{"0":["House Name","Mobile Number","Name","Phone Number","Postcode","Street","Sumame","Town Name","e-Mail Address (required)"]}}
```

It seems to me that I ought to be able to execute that post against any one of those key values. So....

[https://{endpoint}/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/models/{id}/analyze?keys=Name](https://%7Bendpoint%7D/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/models/%7Bid%7D/analyze?keys=Name)

Should pull back whatever the value is associated with the Name key (and there is a value) but instead I get a 200 success and no workable information.

```
"status": "success",
"pages": [
    {
        "number": 1,
        "height": 756,
        "width": 471,
        "clusterId": null,
        "keyValuePairs": [],
        "tables": []
    }
],
"errors": []
}
```

I think I am misunderstanding how to do this properly

Comment: The solution was that I was using a bad form to analyze against.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see the key and an associated value when you try the /analyze call without the query param "keys"?

Comment: I get all the key value pairs returned in what looks proper to me.